# How change Minimized/Maximized state of hidden window without showing it?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

If I use `SetWindowPlacement` with `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` or `ShowWindow` with `SW_MAXIMIZE` my hidden window gets displayed.

I understand that after calling this functions I can call `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE` but it cause some flicking (window gets showed and hide for a while) is there any way to maximize window without displaying it?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Changing an invisible window's size has the same observable effect as not changing an invisible window's size. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Whatever you need it for, you can `SendMessage` [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360) with `SC_MAXIMIZE`

Comment: Why do I need this, this is second question and it too long to describe current reason. I can said example where it can be useful , "all modal and modal less dialogs have some base dialog which has functionality to save and restore size of dialog of last session. This code can be generic and can work for both visible and invisible windows, but If i use `SW_MAXIMIZE` it will always show hidden window which is not very good"

Comment: You should be able to restore your child dialogues to their correct state and positions without any flickering. Is that what you are trying to do? This includes visibility scenarios. Just need to ensure I understand your question before I answer.

Comment: Why you need to maximize an hidden window?